# A way to find one in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

The model method read() in CakePHP returns only one record, so we don't need to loop arround the result set as follws:

```
//In Controller
$item = $this->Item->read(null,$id);
$this->set(compact('item'));

//In View
echo $item['Item']['title'];
```

However, I'd like to be able to control the result through some conditions and read() method does not offer the ability to add conditions, so I have to use find() method as follows:

```
//In controller
$item = $this->Item->find('all',array('conditions' => array('id' => $id, 'lock' => 'yes')));
$this->set(compact('item'));

//In View
echo $item[0]['Item']['title'];
```

Is there any solution allows find to return only one record, i.e. I don't have to deal with $item[0] and just $item as the first example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never ever use read(), always use find(first):

```
$item = $this->Item->find('first', $options);
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first

read() is concidered bad practice as it changes the model itself and usually does more harm than good - especially if you don't know or expect the exact results of this method.

Comment: its not. at least not in the current versions of it. what source are you referring to? it has also been removed from the (official) tutorials. See: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default/actions/controller_actions.ctp

Comment: nice question and logic to deal with out [0]. :)

Comment: @mark The upgrade is very good idea. However, I stuck at some projects I started them with CakePHP 1.2.x and I don't need more time delay in-order to manage migration.